# WSGI App not found - 404

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Following this guide:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

I was not able to configure a "Hello World" WSGI application (I did not mount at docroot and did not delegate to daemon)
on my ubuntu squeeze. Python version is 2.6.5.
I believe mod_wsgi is installed correctly.
Here is what I did:

- Created a user /home/wsgitest (I know we are not supposed to do this but it's just for testing).
- Added the user to group www-data, which is what apache2 runs under:

  ```
  groups wsgitest
  wsgitest : wsgitest www-data
  ```

  As wsgitest, added permissions to read the folder explicitly:

  ```
  chmod -R g+rx wsgitest
  ```
- Created a WSGI Application Script File with the exact same contents from the guide:

  ```
  ls -la /home/wsgitest/
  (...)
  -rw-r--r-- 1 wsgitest wsgitest  277 May  7 17:11 application.wsgi
  ```
- Created an application config file:

  ```
  cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/application.conf 
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias /application /home/wsgitest/application.wsgi
    <Directory /home/wsgitest>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

(File belongs to root:root)

- Enabled the site:

  ```
  ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
  (..)
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 May  9 15:29 application.conf -> ../sites-available/application.conf
  ```
- Restarted apache2 and went to the following address:

  ```
  <ip-address>/application
  <ip-address>/application/
  ```

which gives 404.

- Disabled the site and put the follwing at bottom of file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf :

  ```
  <Directory /home/wsgitest>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>        
  WSGIScriptAlias /application /home/wsgitetst/application.wsgi
  ```
- Restarted apache and tried to navigate again, no changes.
- Tried with lynx and localhost, no changes.
- Enabled logging info level in apache2. The /var/log/apache2 access log tells me that the request is answered with "404 503",
  And this is from error.log:

  ```
  [Wed May 09 15:39:28 2012] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=27914): Attach interpreter ''.
  (...) 
  [Wed May 09 15:39:32 2012] [error] [client <ip>] File does not exist: /var/www/application
  (...)
  [Wed May 09 15:39:28 2012] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=27914): Cleanup interpreter ''.
  ```

The "other_vhosts_access.log" is empty.

To me it looks like the request never reaches the wsgi app or isn't routed somehow...
Can anyone help me identify the problem?

Comment: Add a syntax error, eg., 'xxx' on a line by itself, to Apache configuration and try a restart. See if Apache complains about syntax error. This will confirm files being read. Then watch http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations as there should have been an Apache error message logged as to why the 404 occurred. Examples are in that presentation.

Comment: Thanks for your help Graham, that might come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh no. I did check everything 3 or 4 times but still there was a typo in there.
As you can see in the declaration of WSGIScriptAlias from the apache2.conf edit (wsgitetst).
The include config still won't work, but that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

In application.wsgi must be *application* callable object (case sensitive)

http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_application_interface

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do have the following in my /home/wsgitest/application.wsgi file: def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]

Comment: Consider improving your answer by writing complete sentences.